# Ruby error: NoMethodError: undefined method `SpecificVisibleTreasures' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

So I'm writing this game in ruby, and I have this fuction:

```
puts "Monsters that make you loose a hand-weapon"
  for m in monsters
    specificTreasures = Array.new
    specificTreasures = m.bc.SpecificVisibleTreasures + m.bc.specificHiddenTreasures
    for treasure in specificTreasures
      if (treasure == TreasureKind::ONEHAND)
        puts m.to_s
        break
      end
    end
  end
```

bc is "badconsequence" and bc points to a class "monster" which has this:

```
def initialize(name, level, prize, bc)
    @name = name
    #@combatLevel = level
    @level=level
    @prize = prize
    @badConsequence = bc
  end
```

and the class badconsequence:

```
def initialize(aText, someLevels, someVisibleTreasures, someHiddenTreasures, someSpecificVisibleTreasures, someSpecificHiddenTreasures, death)
    @text = aText
    @levels = someLevels
    @nVisibleTreasures = someVisibleTreasures
    @nHiddenTreasures = someHiddenTreasures
    @SpecificVisibleTreasures = someSpecificVisibleTreasures
    @SpecificHiddenTreasures = someSpecificHiddenTreasures
    @death = death
  end
```

but it gives me this error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `SpecificVisibleTreasures' for nil:NilClass

help please?

Comment: Can't reproduce this from these bits of code. But the problem is that `m.bc` is somehow nil. Find out why.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thank you, yes, I know I cannot put all the code, cause it's huge, but that code only affects to the parts I wrote above. Why it doesn't work is what I'm trying to discover..

Comment: Well, don't put *all* of the code. Reduce it to a **minimal** example that **still works** and shows the problem. It is likely that you will find the problem in the process.

Comment: maybe try to reject nil from `monsters` before iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, **thank you all**, I already fixed it. it was a `attr_accessor` in one of the classes and I changed the main using a different loop type:

```
monsters.each do |monstruo|
```

....

so yep that's it, it works now.